# String check with 2 tables and grab data

Tags: r, match, extract

I have two tables table1 with document names and table2 with document codes and info of the document.
I want to check if the documentnumber in table2 is in the name in table1 and than extract from table2 the info to table1.

I want to check each line in table1 against all numbers of table 2

Table1:

```
 Documentname
 29.01.00-03.001.doc
 22.01.01-03.001-B-Offerteproces - procedure.docx
 29.01.01-01.001-B-Offerteproces algemeen.docx
 29.01.01-01.002-B-Aanbieden - offerteproces.docx
 29.01.01-01.002e-B-Quotation process.docx
 29.01.01-01.003-B-RFQ announcement - offerteproces.docx
 29.01.01-01.004-B-Offerteinformatie complementeren - offerteproces.docx
 29.01.01-01.005-B-Offerteplanning - offerteproces.docx
 29.01.01-01.006-B-Handover quotation - offerteproces.docx
 29.01.01-01.007-B-Elektrisch ontwerp - offerteproces.docx
```

Table2:

```
Documentnumber      new                 old             Status  Revision
C-06-100-02-VM      29.04.40-10.002e    K-15-0-004.3e   Vervallen   E
EM-15-0-3.4         29.02.70-07.020.6   KO-03-ES-020.6  Vervallen   C
KO-03-E2-020.6      29.02.70-07.020.6   EM-15-0-3.4     Vervallen   C
KO-03-TF-43.4       29.02.02-07.043.4   BE-03-IS-10.1   Vervallen   A
P-10-001-02-KAM     29.60.01-03.002     TF-00-0-0.9     Vervallen   E
29.02.02-07.043.4   29.02.01-00.100.2   KO-03-TF-43.4   Vervallen   A
29.04.30-03.003     29.04.30-03.004     BM-06-0-3.1     Vervallen   A
29.04.30-03.006     29.04.23-03.003     BM-06-0-3.4     Vervallen   A
29.04.30-03.010     29.04.10-03.006     BM-15-0-3.1     Vervallen   A
29.04.30-03.016     29.04.30-03.005     BM-04-0-3.2     Vervallen   A
29.04.30-03.017     29.04.30-03.005     BM-04-0-3.3     Vervallen   A
29.04.30-04.002     29.04.30-04.005     BM-05-0-3.2     Vervallen   A
29.04.30-10.001     29.04.23-10.001     BM-01-0-4.1     Vervallen   A
29.04.30-10.002     29.04.23-10.002     BM-04-0-4.1     Vervallen   A
29.04.30-10.011     29.04.23-10.003     BM-04-0-4.2     Vervallen   A
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, and what did and didn't work.

Comment: How about doing a [fuzzy join](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no match in your sample data between numbers in Table1 and Table2, but this should work.

for each line of Table1 I check if the number is in any line of Table2, that gives me a Boolean matrix. If there's at least one TRUE per row, it nmeans the number from Table1 is in table2, if there's at least one TRUE per col, it means the number from table 2 is in table1. I append these results to the tables in the end.

```
bool_mat <- unlist(sapply(Table2$Documentnumber,grepl,Table1$Documentname)) # each row represents a row from Table1, each col a row from Table2
Table1$number_in_table2 <- apply(bool_mat,1,any)
Table2$number_in_table1 <- apply(bool_mat,2,any)
```